# How parse json viewport from Google Places api?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, google-api, google-places-api

With my ios app i made a request to the google places api and i get a response like this:

```
{
 "html_attributions" : [],
"result" : {
  "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "Rome",
        "short_name" : "Rome",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Rome",
        "short_name" : "Rome",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Metropolitan City of Rome",
        "short_name" : "RM",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Lazio",
        "short_name" : "Lazio",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Italy",
        "short_name" : "IT",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     }
  ],
  "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eRome\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eItaly\u003c/span\u003e",
  "formatted_address" : "Rome, Italy",
  "geometry" : {
     "location" : {
        "lat" : 41.9027835,
        "lng" : 12.4963655
     },
     "viewport" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 42.0505462,
           "lng" : 12.7302888
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 41.769596,
           "lng" : 12.341707
        }
     }
  },
  "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
  "id" : "c201ff6d6339dac3b34184b3972b232aa097ff8a",
  "name" : "Rome",
  "place_id" : "ChIJu46S-ZZhLxMROG5lkwZ3D7k",
  "reference" : "CnRoAAAAUe_x9QmJ7kGAAAoyOwa_6vGISj0hy4mvqTJNjNl9TrXqaowyKQCEQov70GTyVidSdNd9wy0MG9UWffjSmi58YG7R3j2Fr9_RoKJCjKgcxwijojmVgFNf5p-8Ja1E53D_YnzW8R0lgtY1xMmOZvxzEBIQ1ruuMP92aFYZs-EJd0McJRoUOaLCDU0K4Dh9nag9wouUAsHqC3g",
  "scope" : "GOOGLE",
  "types" : [ "locality", "political" ],
  "url" : "https://maps.google.com/maps/place?q=Rome,+Italy&ftid=0x132f6196f9928ebb:0xb90f770693656e38",
  "vicinity" : "Rome"
},
"status" : "OK"
}
```

I get the address_components with this code:

```
   NSDictionary *ResultDictionary = [body objectFromJSONString];
   for (NSDictionary *q in [[ResultDictionary valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"address_components"]) {


        NSArray *type=[q valueForKey:@"types"];
        NSArray *long_name=[q valueForKey:@"long_name"];
        NSArray *short_name=[q valueForKey:@"short_name"];
 }
```

With the same logic i can't get the viewport and location value under the geometry object, this cause a crash because the key does not exists :

```
 for (NSDictionary *q in  [[ResultDictionary valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"geometry"] ) {


       NSArray *location=[q valueForKey:@"location"];
   }
```

It seems that the json decode extract only a string and not a nsDictionary for geometry object, what's wrong?

Comment: in which line u got the crash ?

Comment: Try with this line directly and then check once . if this done the after u will able to get your data from this Json responce .[[[ResultDictionary valueForKey:@"result"]objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"]

Comment: with this i can get the value  NSMutableDictionary *NewDict=[[[ResultDictionary valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"]; If you post an answer i'll mark it as correct

Comment: if you satisfied my answer so pls upvote also .thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this on your code and Get your value from `JSON`as per your requiremnt

```
NSMutableDictionary *NewDict=[[[ResultDictionary valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"];

NSString *lat=[NewDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
NSString *lng =[NewDict objectForKey:@"lng"];
```

i hope this code is useful for you.

Comment: @user31929 check this answer

Answer (score 0):

Your "geometry" node contains two dictionaries, and only one of them has the "location" node, that's why it crashes (you ask both of them to give back the value of key "location" without checking first if there is one). The answer provided will fix your issue, just drill straight to the "location" part without iterating and you'll get your values.

Considering you've already got your answer, you'll probably save yourself a few headaches by using a higher level JSON library such as this one: http://www.jsonmodel.com/